# What is the most efficient form of communication

Tags: language-formation, thought

Writing, speaking, typing, body signals and more are all ways to transfer thoughts between humans.
But what is the fastest, most efficient, or most reliable of these methods?

Thank you for your feedback. I respect this does not fit "English language and Usage". The new question is up in Linguistics as proposed by you.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Here you can ask questions specifically about language.

Comment: Those three very different things would all depend on a host of contextual variables, including the content and purpose of the communication, the rhetorical artistry of the source (including the source's understanding of the recipients), and the number of the recipients (though arguably the preposition *between* fixes that at one). But even specifying all that might not make this question answerable, for how could you ever establish that one and the same thought has been transferred from one human mind to another?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. For example a BMI (Brain Machine Interface) would most certainly be the most efficient, fastest and reliable. However ideas of for example spacial reasoning are better explained in pictures from the recipient and far more effort from the sender. Then on the other hand writing is reasonably fast but while the text is written, often the recipient has to wait. This issue does not exist with speech as it is real-time transmitted. It is obviously situation dependent but I was curious to hear more thoughts.

Comment: This question is not specifically about English usage. It should find a more suitable home.

Comment: Smoke signals, obviously!

Comment: Hahaha good one!

Comment: @Cascabel, wouldn't you say that this is very suitable to "English Language & USAGE"?

Comment: It could apply to almost _any_ language. That makes it too broad for this site. And how do you do a "body signal" in English? They are usually cultural.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the mechanics of the English language, but far broader. Probably fine on Linguistics: they have a psycholinguistics tag.

Comment: Don't get me wrong...I think this potentially a fascinating question, just not here. Consider doing a little research, and then re-posting to Linguistics.SE...They will be _more_ deamnding than we are here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is fascinating. It might become closed because some will think it a matter of opinion rather than fact or authoritative reference. Nevertheless there are objective and quantitative aspects to it that deserve thought.

One quantitative approach is to ask how much information is transferred by these methods.

Information is often measured digitally as bits.

Look at an interesting account of the speed of bit transfer in speech:

> [science mag](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/09/human-speech-may-have-universal-transmission-rate-39-bits-second#:%7E:text=Human%20speech%20may%20have%20a,bits%20per%20second%20%7C%20Science%20%7C%20AAAS)

I suspect that this is higher than may be achieved by typing or writing because

Speech words per minute are about 150 to 200

> [Clearly speaking](https://clearly-speaking.com/what-is-the-ideal-rate-of-speech/)

Typing words per minute are about 70 or so

> [Small businesss](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/good-typing-speed-per-minute-71789.html)

Writing speed is discussed in

> [Stack Exchange ELL](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48114/handwriting-speed)

In word terms, writing rate is less than speaking rates.

All this suggests that speaking is faster than typing and writing so in terms of bit rate is the fastest. Body language may be fast for simple messages in brief spells of time but is clearly limited in actual definable information transfer rates.

As to efficiency and reliability, these are more matters of opinion, depending as they do on the recipient as much as on the author of the information.

Comment: I certainly agree on some points you're making but you haven't thought about the receiving end: While listening at <200 wpm is faster in creation, reading with <300 wpm can arguably exceed speech in the speed. Then comes reaction time: When writing, lets say a text message, the recipient has to wait until a logically coherent part of the text is formulated to receive it. Speech on the other hand is usually emission and absorption (interesting wording, i know) at the (almost) same time. Furthermore pictures or movies as an example are high effort but fast understanding

Comment: I just think it is interesting to think about how each medium is in its effectiveness compared to others. And maybe there is a general trend for one to outperform the others

Comment: @mdre I thought about these aspects but such a question is almost impossible to answer fully on a site like this. It deserves a substantial essay or thesis. All any of us here can do is try to help identify the main threads of the analysis. In answering I was aware that it may attract more closure votes than answers, but I felt the issues so interesting that I refrained from closure. I suspect others will do that anyway, for good site criteria reasons.

Comment: As I expected, I have been marked down by a formalist, probably because your question does not meet the site guidelines exactly. But it was worth it to point you in a direction that may answer what is a far more interesting question than many of the trivial things that fit the criteria and that we usually deal with here.

Comment: I haven't added to the downvote, but trust you've close-voted, recommending a transfer to the correct site, Linguistics?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It has been pointed out to me in the past that _both_ answering _and_ VTCing is not considered ethical...I did not DV the answer either.

Comment: @Cascabel I DV to flag a problem, usually what I judge to be inaccuracy or arrogation (lack of supporting reference). This is not a bad response, but answering the question is wrong. But someone else has already flagged this fault (encouraging further off-topic questions by endorsing with an 'answer'). But I see no moral failing in CVing an obviously off-topic question and DVing an answer by someone who knows better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree... mostly. Truth be told, I was seriously tempted to DV this answer to discourage others like it, but it would go against my personal policy. Anton is a very enthusiastic user, however...questions like this are out of place.

Comment: ... I've been known to use a too-basic question as a platform from which to explore a complex related topic (but always relevant to the site). It needs some editing, and goes a lot further than the 'yes'/'no' the OP really wanted.

Comment: I hope we communally have both informed and helped the questioner. I have at last closed because enough has been said.